# Altering candidate key in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, foreign-keys, database-schema, alter-table

I have a rather interesting task ahead of me and I want to make sure I am thinking it out correct -

I have a table `Part` that has its `part_id` being used as part of the candidate keys of several other tables (`A`, `B`, `C`).  I need to drop `Part` and use `Product` instead. `A`, `B`, `C` need to have their `part_id` column (which is of type `bigint`) replaced with a new column of `product_id` (which is of datatype `int`). I need to use the `part_id` column of the tables to determine what `product_id` I need to use for each row.

Here is what I am thinking is what I need to do (thoughts?):

1. create the `product_id` column in each of the tables (`A`, `B`, `C`)
2. set the `product_id` of each row for each table to the appropriate value
3. drop any constraints/fk/pk I have for the `part_id` column in `A`, `B`, `C`
4. drop the `part_id` from those tables completely
5. recreate the constraints/fk/pk I dropped earlier, only have `product_id` be part of them instead
6. drop the `Part` table completely

Can anyone see any potential issues that I may be neglecting?

Thanks!

Additional Info: Tables **A, B**, and **C** each have LOTS of data, so if there is more performant way, I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create new constraints on product_id before you drop constraints on part_id, and before you drop the column part_id. And you should do it in that way--create the new constraints first.

If things go wrong with the product_id changes, your database is still usable if the part_id constraints are still in place.